# PHP foreach if and use of || with variables

Tags: php

I have the following snippet in a block of code and I need to make sure I am understanding it correctly.  As I understand it, doesn't this contradict itself?  What is the point of having this RecordType==2 and also !=2?

**Snippet:**

```
if( ($row['RecordType']==2 && $row['AssignedTech'] == $empnumber) || ($row['RecordType']!=2))
```

**My Interpretation:**

If the RecordType EQUALS 2 AND AssignedTech EQUALS $empnumber OR RecordType DOES NOT EQUAL 2

Comment: Yes your interpretation is right, but what's the question now? Also *What is the point of having this RecordType==2 and also !=2?*, because `RecordType==2` has a second Condition, which also has to be true

Comment: So basically perform this if RecordType==2 or RecordType!=2 ...okay, got it...LOL....

Comment: Can't tell you, you have to decide it! Just think about what answer do you expect from this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be simplified to:

```
if ($row['RecordType'] !=2 || $row['AssignedTech'] == $empnumber)
```

If `RecordType` is 2, then `AssignedTech` should be `$empnumber`, otherwise it doesn't matter and we're all good.